# How to increase the value of an input using Event Delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am building a cart page where a number of quantity can be an increase. Based on the UI design of the page, I can't use the default increase and decrease arrow that comes with `input number type` by default.

I was able to achieve it by using SVGs arrows and styling it.

Here is the way my code is

```
{% for item in cart.items %}

...
        <div  class="cart-quantity-page">
          <input type="number" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="Quantity" value="{{ item.quantity }}"
            min="1" step="1">
            <div class="arrow-cart">
              <div class="arrowtopcart">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10.439" height="10.439" viewBox="0 0 10.439 10.439">
                <path id="Path_36640" data-name="Path 36640" d="M7.381,0V7.381H0Z" transform="translate(5.219 10.439) rotate(-135)" fill="#5e00dd"/>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div class="arrowbtncart">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10.439" height="10.439" viewBox="0 0 10.439 10.439">
                  <path id="Path_36641" data-name="Path 36641" d="M7.381,0V7.381H0Z" transform="translate(5.219) rotate(45)" fill="#5e00dd"/>
                </svg>                
              </div>                            
            </div>
        </div>
...
{% endfor %}
```

Since the `cart-quantity-page` is looping multiple items, the id of the input is different per input

I tried to use event delegation to get the input id, it works, but that is when I click on the input itself

```
let cartqty = document.getElementById("cartqty")

cartqty.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        console.log(e.target.id)

  if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains('arrowbtncart'))
  {
    console.log(e.target.classList.contains('Quantity'))
    console.log('this is bottom arrow')
  }
  if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains('arrowtopcart'))
  {
    console.log('this is top arrow')
  }
});
```

> I am only for a way to increase/decrease the value of the `input.value` using `.stepUp() or .stepDown()`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it like this

```
let cartqty = document.getElementById("cartqty")
cartqty.addEventListener("click", function next(e) {
  let ttar = 'updates_' + e.target.id;
  let inputvaluee = document.getElementById(ttar)
  if (e.target.classList.contains('arrowbtncart')) {
    inputvaluee.stepDown()
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains('arrowtopcart')) {
    inputvaluee.stepUp()
  }
```